# How to change the column headers of a sas dataset into an observation?

Tags: sas

I have created a sas code which generates many sas datasets. Now I want to append all of them to a single excel file . So first I want to convert all the column headers of sas datasets as first observation. Then leave space between these datasets (adding a blank observation). How can we do it?

Comment: what do you mean by row name?

Comment: Sry.. Its column header

Comment: What is it you want in your EXCEL file? It sounds like you want to write many datassets into the same sheet in the excel file.  Why ?  Perhaps you just want to use ODS and PRINT to the EXCEL file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way to do this would be to use `dictionary.columns`

```
proc sql;
create table Attribute as
select * from dictionary.columns;
```

Read through the table and check what attributes you are interested in. For your case you might be interested in the column `"NAME"` <- consist of the name of all columns.

Modify the table by adding `where` statement to the `proc sql` based on the identity of the column ( from which library / what type of file / name of file)  e.g. `where upcase(libname)= "WORK"`

```
data attribute;
array column [ n ] $ length ;
do i=1 to n;
set attribute ( keep = name) ;
column [ i ] = name ;
end;
run;
```

Then I would proceed with data step. You could use macro variable to store the value of column's names by `select variable into :` but anyhow you still need to hardcode the size for the array `n` or any other method that store value into one observation . Also remember define the length and the type of array accordingly. You can give name to the variable in the result dataset `Attribute` by adding `var1-varn`after the `length` at `array` statement.

For simplicity I use `set` statement to read observation one and one and store the value of column `NAME`, which is the official column name derived when using dictionary.columns into the array

Note that creating a non-temporary array would create variable(s) .

Add if you want to add the blank,

```
  data younameit ;
  merge attribute attribute(firstobs=2 keep=name rename=(name=_name));
  output;
  if name ne _name then do;
  call missing(of _all_);
  output;
  end;
  run;
```

As two datasets start with different observation and column names do not duplicate within one dataset, the next row of a valid observation ( derived from the first `output` statement in the resulting dataset would be empty due to `call missing ( of _all_ ) ; output;`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want to combine the datasets and write the results to the Excel file.  Do you really need the extra empty row?

```
libname out xlsx 'myfile.xlsx';
data out.report ;
  set ds1 ds2 ...;
run;
```

Comment: the problem is it is adding extra columns for those columns which are not matching with previous one

Comment: Why do they not match?  And if they do not match then why are you putting them into the same Excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that all your columns are character (or numeric, substitute *numeric*), then in your data step use:

```
array names{*} _character_;
do i=1 to dim(names);
    call label(names{i}, names{i}); 
end;
output;
```